# Rest Spring boot converts a response with duplicate object to id of that object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, response-entity

I write a rest spring boot that return List<Map<String,Object>> as response.

```
public List<Map<String,Object>> getAll(@Valid DataRequestDto dto)
    {
        List<Map<String,Object>> data = (List<Map<String, Object>>) dataOperationMap.getAllData(dto);
        return data;
    }
```

An example of expected output is as follow:

```
    {
        "id": 7581,
        "serialid": 24,
        "parentid": 7576,
        "rowno": 5,
        "code": "15005",
        "acckind": {
            "id": 10080001,
            "title": "بودجه ای",
            "systemDefine": 1,
            "typeValueId": 1,
            "isActive": true,
            "isDefault": true,
            "engTitle": ""
        },
        "accbalance": {
            "id": 10160001,
            "title": "خنثی و بدون کنترل",
            "systemDefine": 1,
            "typeValueId": 1,
            "isActive": true,
            "isDefault": true,
            "engTitle": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7582,
        "serialid": 24,
        "parentid": 7576,
        "rowno": 6,
        "code": "15006",
        "acckind": {
            "id": 10080001,
            "title": "بودجه ای",
            "systemDefine": 1,
            "typeValueId": 1,
            "isActive": true,
            "isDefault": true,
            "engTitle": ""
        },
        "accbalance": {
            "id": 10160001,
            "title": "خنثی و بدون کنترل",
            "systemDefine": 1,
            "typeValueId": 1,
            "isActive": true,
            "isDefault": true,
            "engTitle": null
        }
    }
```

but "accKind" and "accBalance" From the second data onwards, have been replaced by id only, as follow:

```
    {
        "id": 7581,
        "serialid": 24,
        "parentid": 7576,
        "rowno": 5,
        "code": "15005",
        "acckind": {
            "id": 10080001,
            "title": "بودجه ای",
            "systemDefine": 1,
            "typeValueId": 1,
            "isActive": true,
            "isDefault": true,
            "engTitle": ""
        },
        "accbalance": {
            "id": 10160001,
            "title": "خنثی و بدون کنترل",
            "systemDefine": 1,
            "typeValueId": 1,
            "isActive": true,
            "isDefault": true,
            "engTitle": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7582,
        "serialid": 24,
        "parentid": 7576,
        "rowno": 6,
        "code": "15006",
        "acckind": 10080001,
        "accbalance": 10160001,
    }
```

I want the whole object to be displayed in all the list data.

in debug I understood that the data is correct until it is returned, and it is changed in the conversion to json.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hushaerp</groupId>
    <artifactId>form-manager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>form-manager</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: How do you convert that into json?  Which library do you use?

Comment: You need to show us what JSON converter you use, also show us what's inside DataRequestDto

Comment: @Rudy I used default spring boot rest settings. I added my project pom.xml to question